# Looking for a summary of which version of XSLT is supported in each major browser

Tags: xslt, browser

Does anyone know of a resource which summarises which version of XSLT is supported in different versions of the major browsers?

Answer (score 2):

> -- http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/xsl_browsers.asp

**Mozilla Firefox**

Firefox 3 supports XML, XSLT, and XPath.

**Internet Explorer**

Internet Explorer 6 supports XML, XSLT, and XPath.

Internet Explorer 5 is NOT compatible with the official W3C XSL Recommendation.

**Google Chrome**

Chrome 1 supports XML, XSLT, and XPath.

**Opera**

Opera 9 supports XML, XSLT, and XPath. Opera 8 supports only XML + CSS.

**Apple Safari**

Safari 3 supports XML and XSLT.

Comment: Which version of XSLT for each of those?

Comment: It's safe to say that trying to use anything other than XSLT 1.0 is futile.

Comment: What about Internet Explorer 7 and 8?

Comment: @Simon: IE has supported native XSLT 1.0 since IE6.0 <gasp/>, though support was restricted from same-domain use.

Answer (score 1):

No browser supports anything above XSLT 1.0 at present.

Current XSLT 2.0 processors include Saxon, Gestalt, Altova and possible an IBM processor in beta.